# Populate list only in current row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic add rows. Every row contains 2 dropdowns (`select`). They are for **type** and **category** selections. The category depends on the type.

The problem is when I change a `select` option, it also affects other rows, which is not my intention.

For example, when there are 3 rows. How can I improve this function so it only affects specific `select` options?

Here is my HTML code

```
<table id="dynamic_field">  
    <tr>        
        <td>
            <label>Vehicle Type:</label>
            <select name="vehicle_type[]" class="" id="" onchange="get_category(this.value)">
                <option value="">Type</option>
                <option value="Car">Car</option>
                <option value="Bus">Bus</option>                  
            </select>
        </td>   
        <td>
            <label>Vehicle Category</label>
            <select name="vehicle_category[]" class="category" id="category" onchange="get_sub_category(this.value)" >
                <option value="">Category</option>
            </select>
        </td> 
        <td>
            <label>Vehicle Sub Category</label>
            <select name="vehicle_sub_category" class="form-control subcategory">
                <option value="">Sub Category</option>
            </select>
        </td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <!--- etc. --->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
function get_category(key){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getCat',
        type: "get",
        data: {type:key},
        success: function(data){ // What to do if we succeed
            $('.category').empty();
            $('.subcategory').empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                $('.category').append($('<option>', {
                    value: d.id,
                    text : d.V_Category
                }));
            });
        }
    });         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `onchange` HTML attributes:

```
onchange="get_category(this.value)"
```

Instead bind the event handling via code, and find the corrsponding category/subcategory. As your related `select` elements are in neighboring `td` elements, you need to first get the row where the current `select` is in, and then find the other, category element:

```
$("[name*=vehicle_type]").change(function () {
    var $type = $(this); // get the current select element
    var $row = $type.closest("tr"); // find the row that has the related select elements
    var $cat = $("[name*=vehicle_category]", $row); // .. the category-select
    var $subcat = $("[name*=vehicle_sub_category]", $row); // .. the subcategory-select
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getCat',
        type: "get",
        data: { type: $type.val() },
        success: function(data) {
            $cat.empty();
            $subcat.empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                $cat.append($('<option>', {
                    value: d.id,
                    text : d.V_Category
                }));
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Did you have a go at this? Could you let me know?

Comment: Still i am following your instruction. But It does not appends anything in dropdown

Comment: For me it works. Could you add in your question the *exact* HTML you have for those `select` (and anything you may have between them), and a sample of what `data` looks like?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l8hxnumD8d63dr2JklxLZCdbBAagmOOmWCWJpme1BNk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, and *that* is important information. The fact that those `select` elements are *not* sibling elements, but are embedded inside different table cells is crucial information. I will update my answer...

Comment: eagerly waiting for that

Comment: Updated just now.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. It's working for first row. I am trying for others......

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to poit to te next element in the DOM, ot it will change all the DOM elements with class `category`. So you can use [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) jQuery method.

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves
>   the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Try change your code in:

```
function get_category(key){

      $.ajax({
         url: 'getCat',
         type: "get",
         data: {type:key},
          success: function(data){ // What to do if we succeed
          $(this).next('.category').empty();
          $(this).next('.subcategory').empty();

          $.each(data, function (i, d) {
          $(this).next('.category').append($('<option>', {
            value: d.id,
            text : d.V_Category
             }));
         });

      }
    });

 }
```

Comment: thanks . its working but problem is . it does not empty previous value. If I select twice it appends . That's values become double, triple and so on..... for example bus, bus, car car. how can I fix it?